# How to add homepage to Latex resume

Tags: templates, resume, cv

I am using [this resume template](https://www.overleaf.com/articles/rishi-shahs-resume/vgxvkmxktyxn).

There is no `\homepage` defined in the `resume.cls` file, does this mean I can't add a homepage address?

Comment: You should look for another class. See https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Curriculum_Vitae

Comment: You can define your `\homepage` then. Either define it in your document or go to the source file `resume.cls` and define it.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two cases:

---

#### 1 – You have used one or two `\address`s

You just have to use the last one:

**`main.tex`**

```
etc etc...
\documentclass{resume} % Use the custom resume.cls style

\usepackage[left=0.75in,top=0.6in,right=0.75in,bottom=0.6in]{geometry} % Document margins

\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\tab}[1]{\hspace{.2667\textwidth}\rlap{#1}}
\newcommand{\itab}[1]{\hspace{0em}\rlap{#1}}
\name{Rishi Shah} % Your name
\address{156 Kasturi, Balajinagar, Sangli 416416} % Your address
\address{Homepage: \href{https://tex.stackexchange.com/}{\texttt{https://tex.stackexchange.com/}}} % Your secondary addess (optional)
\address{(+91)9975808780 \\ rishishah105@gmail.com} % Your phone number and email

\begin{document}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

etc etc...
```

---

#### 2 – You have used all three available `\address`s:

First you have to modify `resume.cls` a little bit:

**`resume.cls`**

1. Add

   ```
   \let \@addressfour \relax
   ```

   after `\let \@addressthree \relax`.
2. Change the definition of `\address` to

   ```
   \def \address #1{
       \@ifundefined{@addresstwo}{
           \def \@addresstwo {#1}
       }{
           \@ifundefined{@addressthree}{
               \def \@addressthree {#1}
           }{
               \@ifundefined{@addressfour}{
                   \def \@addressfour {#1}
               }{
                   \def \@addressone {#1}
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Change `\renewcommand{\document}{}`:

   ```
   \renewcommand{\document}{
       \ori@document  % Begin document
       \printname % Print the name specified with \name
       \@ifundefined{@addressone}{}{ % Print the first address if specified
           \printaddress{\@addressone}}
       \@ifundefined{@addresstwo}{}{ % Print the second address if specified
           \printaddress{\@addresstwo}}
       \@ifundefined{@addressthree}{}{ % Print the third address if specified
           \printaddress{\@addressthree}}
       \@ifundefined{@addressfour}{}{
           \printaddress{\@addressfour}}
   }
   ```

Now you only have to add another `\address` command:

**`main.tex`**

```
etc etc...
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass{resume} % Use the custom resume.cls style

\usepackage[left=0.75in,top=0.6in,right=0.75in,bottom=0.6in]{geometry} % Document margins

\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\tab}[1]{\hspace{.2667\textwidth}\rlap{#1}}
\newcommand{\itab}[1]{\hspace{0em}\rlap{#1}}
\name{Rishi Shah} % Your name
\address{156 Kasturi, Balajinagar, Sangli 416416} % Your address
\address{Somewhere in the world} % Your secondary addess (optional)
\address{(+91)9975808780 \\ rishishah105@gmail.com} % Your phone number and email
\address{Homepage: \href{https://tex.stackexchange.com/}{\texttt{https://tex.stackexchange.com/}}}

\begin{document}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

etc etc...
```